# Doodles and Scribbles (again!)

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

[image: Doodles and Scribbles 2]

Sooo, I doodled some more stuff on my notebook...
What should I do with this page?

Comment: I think I have answers for all the individual parts, but I can't find the final "What should I do with this page?". Should I post a partial answer, or leave it a bit longer for someone else?

Comment: You can post a partial answer, maybe while writing it you'll discover the final answer to the puzzle!

Comment: Ok, there's a partial answer that's less complete than mine, so I'm going to post what I have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What should you do with this page?

> You should fold it to make something interesting. Preferably something from "Origami to Astonish and Amuse" by Jeremy Shafer

### Favourite songs.

> Searching for singles matching the word lengths indicated by the dashes:
>  Carpenter Brut: Leather Teeth
>  Metallica: One
>  Daft Punk: Robot Rock
>  Justice: Several to choose from - Helix, Randy, D.A.N.C.E.
>  Picking D.A.N.C.E. for the Justice track, and then taking initial letters gives us **LORD**.

### The <strike>stick figures</strike> Modern Art!.

> These look like a pigpen cipher turned into dancing/running stick figures, with the last one suffering a fairly serious injury.
>  It can be decoded to BISHOP HAT; and a bishop's hat is a **MITRE** (or **MITER**).

### The "equations".

> Just taking the numbers, we have 7, 1, 13, 2, 9, 20.
>  Decoding with  A1Z26 gives us **GAMBIT**.

### The three characters.

> For each character, to get their class, take:
>  - the first three letters of their name,
>  - the first letter of their favourite thing,
>  - the first letter of their nature,
>  - and the first and last letters of their job.
>  So Brigitte is a **BRIGAND**:
>
> ```
>  Solomon     Pallandel            Brigitte
>  Dogs        Absolution           Gold
>  Ignorant    Determined           Artistic
>  Ent Killer  Illustrious Paladin  Notable Bard
>  SOLDIER     PALADIN              BRIGAND
> ```

### Putting it all together

> Fitting those four answers into the grid of squares gives us:
>
> ```
>  LORD
>   BRIGAND
>      GAMBIT
>        MITRE
> ```
>
> And (credit to @SeptaCube) if you read down, changing lines at the shared letters you get:
>
> ```
>  L OR D
>   B RIG AND
>       GAM BIT
>         MI TRE
> ```
>
> Giving use **ORIGAMI**

Comment: Rot 13 for final answer: Fgneg ng gur gbc jbeq, zbivat qbja n jbeq ng funerq yrggref, gb trg gur svany nafjre BEVTNZV.

Comment: Those are not stick figures, see it more as modern art, that last one *is* indeed broken though (How dare you criticize my art! :) )

Comment: @SeptaCube Thanks! I don't think I would ever have spotted that.

Comment: @Auribouros My humblest apologies! :-) Now suitably modified.

Comment: @Auribouros In my defence, I should add that the first thing those figures made me think of was [The Adventure of the Dancing Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventure_of_the_Dancing_Men)

Comment: @fljx A fair assumption, I planned for them to be stakes planted into soft ground, or small markings one would see when hiking.

Answer (score 1):

**NOT A SOLUTION (YET)**

**Identifying The Songs**

> Coincidentally, these happen to be some of my favorite artists!
> Carpenter Brut - [Leather Teeth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9r7PQyQJl0g)
> Metallica - [One](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WM8bTdBs-cw)
> Daft Punk - [Robot Rock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFZjqVnWBhc)
> Justice - [D.A.N.C.E.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCnBrrnOefs)
> These songs' first letters spell out "LORD".
> There are some other possible songs like [Randy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hw3d9KTYHIE), [Canon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZ-0IEtHEac), and [Helix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7b7yXi1kds), but these seem to be the artists' more popular pieces.

**Brigitte's Class**

> The character's classes are composed of the following:
>  - The first three letters of their name (SOL, PAL)
>  - The first letter of their favorite thing (SOLD, PALA)
>  - The first letter of their nature (SOLDI, PALAD)
>  - The first and last letters of their job (SOLDIER, PALADIN)
>  Therefore, Brigitte is a BRIGAND (BRI+G+A+ND)